# (Unity) Las plataformas generadas aleatoriamente me colisionan

Tags: unity2d

En unity, tengo un generador de plataformas infinito que me genera plataformas mientras el personaje asciende en el ***eje Y***, el problema es que hay veces que las plataformas se generan encima de otras plataformas y se solapan, me gustaría saber cómo hacer que se separen si colisionan al generarse. He escrito esto esto en el script de las prefabs de las plataformas, pero no funciona. He puesto a todas las plataformas la tag **"Floor"**, o la tag **"Enviroment"**.

(No me escribe el script entero bien, pero es esto)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NoBlocking : MonoBehaviour {


public static Transform trs;



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    trs = GetComponent<Transform>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {



}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enviroment" || col.gameObject.tag == "Floor")
    {
        if (transform.position.x <= 0)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 4f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            Debug.Log(transform.position.x);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - 4f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }
        Debug.Log("hola");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: hola @TebionDL ,  has pensado en usar OnCollisionStay ?.   prueba si te funciona mejor que OnCollisionEnter. ya que uno detecta cuando se entra en contacto y la otra si el contacto se mantiene. saludos

Comment: Sí lo he probado y no funciona, también he probado los tres OnCollision a la vez y nada. Gracias aún así.